# How to install a Steam game on PlayOnLinux?

Tags: steam, playonlinux

I'm quite new to PlayOnLinux so I got really confused as I tried to install some of my Steam games. I'm using the newest version of this program. I installed Steam by selecting it from the installation list. Everything was installed and Steam runs fine. Now I've clicked on the `"Install"` tab and I've chose `"Counter Strike: Global Offensive"`. PlayOnLinux opened an installer and added some things like DirectX and so on, but at one point it wanted to install Steam again and the Steam setup window opened. My problem is that I already have steam installed and skipping the setup causes an error...
Does anyone know the correct way to add Steam games correctly?

Comment: I'm reviewing this so I can't directly answer,  but try running through that install process again from what it opens...from what I know playonlinux uses an adapted form of wine, which needs a local port of the steam client to be able to run.

Comment: CS:GO runs natively on Linux. Why don't you give that a try instead?

Answer (score 1):

You don't install the games with PlayOnLinux. You will have to install them from within Steam, as they are Steam games.

Comment: But there is a specific Game List especially for Games which can only be executed if steam is installed, so it would be wrong installing them from within steam. And installing the games from the list will make playonlinux use specific settings and versions of vine etc. which are tested with the game and works fine

Answer (score 1):

If you install a game on PlayOnLinux through their list which requires steam. Then it will run the script for installation of that game, install steam for you (windows version), and then the PlayOnLinux script will wait for you to install that game in steam. Afterwards, you will close steam and the script will continue installing the additional files that you need for the game to work. You do not need to install steam beforehand, unless you need just that application specifically.